# How can I install Crypt::SSLeay on a Win 64?

Tags: perl, 64-bit, openssl, perl-module, activestate

I've got 64-bit Vista with ActiveState Perl "v5.10.0 built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread" and I'm trying to get the [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Crypt::SSLeay) package installed along with versions of `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll`.

I've done this before on a Win32 machine using the 'uwinnipeg' server, but I'm running into issues with my 64-bit system.

```
ppm install http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/Crypt-SSLeay.ppd
ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this platform
```

I've tried a straight ppm install which seemed to work, but verification fails and I don't see any sign of the dll files?

```
C:\Perl64\bin>ppm install Crypt::SSLeay 
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...done 
Updating ActiveState Package Repository database...done 
Syncing site PPM database with .packlists...done 
No missing packages to install 
C:\Perl64\bin>ppm verify Crypt::SSLeay 
ppm verify failed: Package 'Crypt::SSLeay' is not installed
```

Does anyone know where/how I could get versions that are compatible with my PC?

Comment: @Alexandr Ciornii that's a good question.  I've been using Perl on Win for small side projects for the past 6 or 7 years now.  Back then ActiveState looked to me like it had the best offering, and I've never really thought to explore any of the other options that have emerged. Maybe I should.

Comment: Sinan Unur was correct.  After looking into the newest Perl versions available, I decided to give Strawberry Perl v5.12.1 a try (which comes with OpenSSL 1.0.0-beta4 10 Nov 2009).  I was then able to install the newest version of Crypt::SSLeay from CPAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues here: First, AFAIK, you need OpenSSL v1.0.0 or greater for Windows 64. Second, until recently, `Makefile.PL` in `Crypt-SSLeay` did not detect correctly OpenSSL versions greater than `0.9.x`.

I think you want to upgrade at the very least to Perl 5.10.1 as it fixed a number of [crucial performance related bugs](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.10.1/perldelta.html#Selected-Bug-Fixes).

If you install `mingw` via ActiveState's `ppm` (I am assuming `ppm install mingw` would work even though I haven't tried it on a 64-bit system), you can use it to build [OpenSSL 1.0.0a](http://openssl.org/source/) and [Crypt-SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay).

Update: You probably don't need `Crypt::SSLeay`. See:

- [DO YOU NEED Crypt::SSLeay?](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay#DO-YOU-NEED-Crypt::SSLeay)
- [Does your code really depend on Crypt::SSLeay?](http://www.nu42.com/2014/04/does-your-code-really-depend-on.html)
- [Don't declare a dependency on Crypt::SSLeay (or IO::Socket::SSL either)](http://www.nu42.com/2014/08/dont-declare-dependency-on-cryptssleay.html).

Also useful:

- [Building OpenSSL 1.0.1g on 64-bit Windows Pro 8.1 with Windows SDK 7.1](http://www.nu42.com/2014/04/building-openssl-101g-on-64-bit-windows.html)
- [Compile Vim and OpenSSL with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](http://www.nu42.com/2014/11/compile-vim-and-openssl-with-visual.html).

Comment: Unur Great information - Thank you. I'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

[Sinan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-unur) has very recently released a new version of [Crypt::SSLeay](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay) which might clear up some Windows installation issues. I doubt it's made its way into a PPM yet.